# After setting authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator in Cassandra.yaml, Cassandra CQL Shell does not run

Tags: windows, cassandra, cqlsh

I'm new in Cassandra. I'm using Datastax Community edition and using only a single node in Windows 7. Trying to change my authentication, set authenticator value from `AllowAllAuthenticator` to `PasswordAuthenticator` in Cassandra.yaml. After that setting, it does not let me to run my Cassandra CQL Shell.

Q1. Why this is happening?

Q2. How to overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you accessing cqlsh?  If you have the password authenticator activated, then you will need to specify the default Cassandra super user with the username and password flags.

Linux:

```
./cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

In Windows, I'm going to guess that it's something like this:

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

Note that once you get in, you'll want to create your own superuser and [disable the default cassandra account, as described here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/security_config_native_authenticate_t.html).

"I'm accessing cqlsh from START-> Datastax Community Edition-> Cassandra CQL Shell"

I wasn't aware that the Windows version now had a shortcut to cqlsh.  Try modifying that shortcut's target ([as shown here](https://superuser.com/questions/358565/adding-command-line-switches-to-windows-shortcuts)), and add `-u cassandra -p cassandra` to the end.  I was able to get this to work by installing and modifying my shortcut's "target" property to this:

```
"E:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\python.exe" "e:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh" -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

Basically, put the `-u` and `-p` flags *outside* of the double quotes, and it should work.

Comment: I'm accessing cqlsh from START-> Datastax Community Edition-> Cassandra CQL Shell

Comment: I changed as you recommended but still CQL shell is not working.

Comment: Before Change-
Target : "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh"      After Change-   Target : "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra"

Comment: I also tried to run "cqlsh"  batch file from the installed folder. Same thing happens. Window just blinks with a message that "Connection Error: Bad Request: you have not logged in"

Comment: @AvijoyChakma Excellent, glad I could help.  Would you mind "accepting" the answer then?  Thanks.

Comment: No problem in accepting that but another problem rises that I can connect to the cassandra as you said but "OpsCenter Web Interface" can not connect to the Cluster now. Did you face the same problem ?